# How to make php class available in function

Tags: php, router-os

I am using a third party class that works well as long as I use it in the main body of my PHP script. If I try to use it in a function that is called from main, it gets a "PHP Fatal error:  Class 'RouterOS\Util' not found error".  What do I need to do in the function so it can use the class?

```
<?php
require_once '/usr/local/sbrc/MTAPI/vendor/autoload.php';
...
    GetNextRouter($loginData[0]['User'], $loginData[0]['Password'], $firstAddress[0]['IPAddress']);
...
}
function GetNextRouter($UserID, $Pass, $Address) {
        $util = new RouterOS\Util($client = new RouterOS\Client($Address, $UserID, $Pass));
...
}
```

The error occurs on the $util = new RouterOS\Util line.

Comment: Is the calling script in a namespace?

Comment: Since you're calling `new RouterOS\Util()` without a leading backslash, you're referring to the current namespace. Thus, if your function is inside another namespace that you've defined, then `RouterOS\Util` actually refers to `YourNamespace\RouterOS\Util`. If this is the case, then you can simply use `new \RouterOS\Util()` with a leading blackslash. This anchors the class name to the root namespace.

Comment: echo namespace constant inside the function and check if you are in global

Comment: you could remove this `}` above the function as it's a syntax error. is error reporting on?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I think that's just a copy-pasta problem. I could be wrong...

Comment: If it's not that would explain why it doesn't work .... lol, I thought the same but had to say something.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix he is getting "PHP Fatal error: Class 'RouterOS\Util' not found error"

Comment: I found it.  Forgot the USE statement.

Comment: Note: You never *need* the `USE` statement. Your error was likely a namespace issue.

Comment: @ScottReed You may want to create an answer for that it would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Adding 
use PEAR2\Net\RouterOS;
solved my issue